# EFL - window hirarchy

Tags: efl

I'm porting a C-language kiosk application to a x86 machine, running Ubuntu 16.
I'm using the EFL GUI framework (version 1.20.7) - it is new to me.
The GUI is quite simple: a few screens, with background images, some buttons, labels and text-entries on each. relevant screen is raised, to be visible, according to application-logic. I did that.
My question: should there be a root-parent-window (container) for all sub-windows? At least in my simple design?
I went through many example programs, but all very specific, none with a bigger GUI.

Another thing that puzzled me was that widgets were created via the root-window, even if they were inserted/located in a child-container (taken from the EFL docs, test_button.c):

```
win = elm_win_util_standard_add("buttons", "Buttons");
bx = elm_box_add(win);
bt = elm_button_add(win);
elm_box_pack_end(bx, bt);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every widget requires a parent, which at the top level is probably a window. It's recommended that this be a logical parent so examples where that is not the case are probably misleading.

If you would like to see a larger application with many windows then maybe you should check out the [EFL IDE](https://github.com/Enlightenment/edi) which is written using the EFL graphical libraries.